# Can ResultSet.getArray(colName) return null?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray(java.lang.String)

Doesn't seem to mention the possibility.

Comment: I suggest using the Javadoc from Java 7 (though it might not make that much difference)

Answer (score 2):

No. It throws `SQLException` if the column does not exist.

If you are considering that the column exists and all its values are null, then it will return an array of null values.

Comment: The column is of type Integer[]; but has value null, what you are saying is it retuns { null } ? or {}

Comment: I am saying {null, null...}

Comment: Nope, at least with postgresql and h2 it returns null

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the column is NULL in the database, ResultSet::getArray will return null.